# In GitLab, is it possible to automatically create an issue from a pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am planning to run some validations against the pull request in a CI pipeline and, based on the validation results, I wish to automatically create an issue and assign it to developers.

Is this achievable in a GitLab pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to create a single issue, go with the `cURL` command. However, if you require more complex logic, the [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/issues.html#project-issues) library can be a useful tool in your arsenal.

To create a project issue:

```py
import gitlab
import os

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(os.environ['CI_SERVER_URL'], private_token=os.environ['PRIVATE_TOKEN'])
project = gl.projects.get(os.environ['CI_PROJECT_ID'])

issue_details = {
'title': f'Validation failed in {os.environ["CI_PROJECT_NAME"]}',
'description': f'Pipeline: {os.environ["CI_PIPELINE_URL"]}',
'assignee_ids': [111, 222]
}
issue = project.issues.create(issue_details )
```

This assumes you have created a [masked variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#mask-a-custom-variable) called `PRIVATE_TOKEN`. The other variables are [pre-defined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

You can add the above code and other logic to a Python script and call it in `gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

```yaml
# Use whatever image you need, but make sure it has Python installed
image: python:3.7
...
handle-failure:
  when: on_failure
  before_script:
    - pip install -r ./cicd/gitlab/requirements.txt
  script:
    - python -m ./cicd/gitlab/create_issue.py
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to call the [New Issue API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue) through a curl call (as [seen here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/46723))

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: PlainTextToken" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/issues?title=a title"
```

You would need to add a private token as a [masked variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variable-requirements).